# Insert new item to wordpress array [PHP]

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, insert

I want to insert new `<li>` element to my function output.

```
function gallery_nav() {
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($myArray as $key ) {
        $i++;
        echo '<li><a href="#">'. $i .'</a></li>';
    }
}
```

It printing this html

```
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
<li>6</li>
<li>7</li>
```

Can i insert custom `<li>` element into this array? Like this:

```
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li class="custom">3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
<li class="custom">6</li>
<li>7</li>
<li>8</li>
<li>9</li>
```

Comment: Yes, easily. Are the "custom" indexes 3 & 6 defined somewhere or just random?

Comment: Yes defined. 3 and 6.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply modify your function to check for a specific iteration number and output something extra:

```
$i = 0;

foreach ($myArray as $item => $value) {
    $i++;

    if ($i % 3 === 0) {
        echo '<li class="custom"><a href="#">' . $i . '</a></li>';
    }

    echo '<li><a href="#">'. $i .'</a></li>';
}
```

This will add an extra `li` element every 3 iterations.

**If you don't want it to add an extra `li` every third iteration, then modify it back to this:**

```
$i = 0;

foreach ($myArray as $item => $value) {
    $i++;

    if ($i % 3 === 0) {
        $class = 'custom';
    } else {
        $class = '';
    }

    echo '<li class="' . $class .'"><a href="#">' . $i . '</a></li>';
}
```

If you only need it on iterations 3 and 6 and no others, modify the condition to this:

```
if ($i === 3 || $i === 6) {
    // code
}
```

Comment: Will it? You aren't using the `$class` variable.

Comment: It adding only class. Look my question again please. First output has 7 elements. Second has 9. So i just want add extra li.

Comment: Updated. You can add an echo statement on every nth iteration.

Comment: Is it possible to make it with foreach? Because my array is complicated. And i need $key and $value

Comment: Yes, you would just switch it to foreach as shown and declare the `$i` outside like you did in your question. @JustBaron has a better answer if your custom indexes are stored somewhere and need to be accessed dynamically.

Comment: It pringting 1-2-3-3-4-5-6-6-7-8-9

Comment: That's because we are adding an extra `li` element, so the number is getting printed twice. The first "3" and "6" should have the custom class. I updated my answer with how to just add the class instead of an extra `li`.

Answer (score 0):

If your custom indexes are assigned in an array, you can do something like this:

```
<?php 
$myArray = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7); # Your original array
$customArray = array(3,6); # Your custom array    
$VarCount = count($myArray); # Set the default loop count

function gallery_nav($myArray, $customArray=NULL, $VarCount) {
    for($i=1; $i<=$VarCount; $i++) {
        $Class = NULL;
        if(in_array($i, $customArray)){
            $VarCount++; # Increment extra <li>
            $Class = "class=\"custom\"";
        }
echo "<li {$Class}><a href=\"#\">{$i}</a></li>
";
    }
}
gallery_nav($myArray,$customArray, $VarCount);
?>
```

Which results in:

```
<li ><a href="#">1</a></li>
<li ><a href="#">2</a></li>
<li class="custom"><a href="#">3</a></li>
<li ><a href="#">4</a></li>
<li ><a href="#">5</a></li>
<li class="custom"><a href="#">6</a></li>
<li ><a href="#">7</a></li>
<li ><a href="#">8</a></li>
<li ><a href="#">9</a></li>
```

[See live demo](https://3v4l.org/PHe03).

Comment: I need with foreach. Because i am using $key and $value

Comment: @wpuzman Then maybe you'll so kind to update your question with where you are proposing to use both `$key` and `$value`. I can then update my answer accordingly...can't guess!

Comment: I think you don't need $key and $value right? just insert a new element.

Comment: @wpuzman You've lost me mate. Your original question doesn't use `$key` and there is no mention of `$value`. You then say that you cannot use my answer due to the fact you need `$key` and `$value`. Now **I** don't need `$key` and `$value`. I'm confused.